# Cannot get page to read the CSS page for a simple div

Tags: css, html

everything in my style sheet will work apart from divs. Kinda strange. I created a test page to try and see why it won't work but no joy.

If I include the div in a  tag at the top of the page it will work. Just not if I link the css file itself. I will put my code below.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />    
</head>

<body>
<div class="boxed">
This should be in a box
</div>
```

And a clean stylesheet. With just the information for the div class.

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.boxed {
border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: All fine from here..
P.S. Close the body and html tag.

Comment: It won't style the div for some reason :(

Comment: The html file and the css are in the same folder? If you add more rules are they applied or are they are all ignored?

Comment: Yep, same folder.
In the page I realised the divs wouldnt work. There was other stuff that was working from the same sheet.

Comment: Possibly stupid question - have you tried using a different class name?

Comment: What about @SpartakusMd suggestion? In the code snippet you gave you don't close the the body and html tags.

Comment: My fault, in the actual page it was closed already closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this, try just typing the full URL  , so instead of "style.css"  ,

```
 type "http://yourWebsite.com/style.css" instead of "style.css"

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

edit: also add type="text/css"

2nd edit:

you also need to have a title in your head, that is required. maybe it's causing this issue, maybe not

```
<head>
<title>This is my Title! </title>  
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried as you suggested. It still won't style the div. :(

Comment: Added that in just now. Still doesn't fix it. It's so strange that the <style> tags will make it work. But not with the link to a StyleSheet.

Comment: I got a host, no content management. Just the files that I upload.

Comment: Thanks, it now works. Strange thing. I had title already on the page before I made the test page and it still wouldn't work.
I have made all the changes as suggested to the main page and it still wouldn't work.
I have now copied and pasted all from main to the test. And it works.
I'm so confused but some how, this fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Style.css file:

```
.boxed {
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried as you have suggested and still no luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

check to see if you haven't misplaced any '}' or semi columns and i don't think you need the
@charset "utf-8" in your stylesheet since you already specified it in your head